# How to copy text from word file/world and use it as body in mail body (smtplib librery) having same fonts and style in python

Tags: python, email, docx

I want to send mail using python(no problem in that) but I want body part to have different fonts, colors, style etc. Basically body part is available with me in a docx file. When I am reading it with docx library or any other library it's just copying text, other styles, and fonts, line gap is missing in that output. Please provide a solution.

Comment: What are you outputting the text to?

Comment: In order to get style into your email, you will need to code it with CSS.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert I have .docx file. I want its content exactly (with fonts and style), to be used as a body in smtplib library.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert Any other way around. I don't want to use HTML/CSS  stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @tobias i had to write it in HTML. but i am a lazy person so i just converted my docx to HTML and then read it in text file from there i copy pasted in body part. It's working like charm